# Why does assembly code differ depending on the disassembler I use?

Tags: c++, debugging, assembly, gdb, disassembly

I am teaching myself to debug assembly language; I am new to assembly. I have a very simple C++ program and I disassembled it 3 times using different disassemblers: GDB, otool, and godbolt.org. GDB and godbolt.org produced approximately the same amount of code (1 page in a word processor), though many lines differ. The otool -tv command produced about 14 pages of code so there are many differences with respect to the GDB and godbolt.org outputs. The assembly code is too long to post. I was expecting the assembly code outputs to be the same as each other. Why are they different and which disassembler is best?

Here is my C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main () {

int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;

a += b;
a = a + c;

std::cout << "Value of A is " << a << std::endl;

return 0;

}
```

An example of assembly differences:

GDB:

```
0x0000000100000f44 <+4>:    sub    $0x30,%rsp
0x0000000100000f48 <+8>:    mov    0x10c1(%rip),%rdi        # 0x100002010
0x0000000100000f4f <+15>:   lea    0xfb6(%rip),%rsi
```

Godbolt.org:

```
sub rsp, 16
mov DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
mov DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 2
```

Otool -tv gave 13 more pages of code than the others so there is an obvious difference there.

Comment: You should at least post an excerpt of the disassembly, preferably something that shows excess things not in the other versions. I expect it's something trivial, such as disassembling data or libraries. Also make sure you disassemble the same binary, otherwise you are really looking at compiler differences, not disassembler.

Comment: you can get very different assembly from this c++ code if you just play a bit with compiler flags, that is the different direction, but still I dont really understand why you expect to get identical assembly from different disassembler

Comment: Using `std::cout` makes the assembly much longer. You might find it better to remove the `std::cout` line (and the `#include <iostream>`), and just do `return a` from main

Comment: I posted an example. I don't know why I suppose they would be the same, perhaps because from the same program I assume they have the same binary code and that translates upwards to assembly? My understanding is not solid though. I will learn more about compilers.

Comment: @MrBerry How were you able to use godbolt.org to disassemble a binary?

Comment: It is hard to believe that the example is disassembly of the same three instructions. To put it beyond doubt - show the object codes too. Are you comparing like with like, or comparing compiler's assembly output with a disassembly of another compiler's output?

Comment: I am going to just use the gdb version consistently and hope that with greater asm knowledge, the equivalence of the two assembly examples I posted will be self-evident. I will avoid using otool -tv for now but I am curious as to why it produces so much more code than the others, perhaps it is std::cout, but 13 pages more for just that one line? That is interesting.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I wasn't I simply posted the code, so that could account for the differences. For otool -tv and gdb I used the same binary.

Comment: godbolt is compiling for itself so you are looking at a different binary. Also, it's switched to intel syntax while your gdb is at&t. Since you ran otool and gdb with the same binary an excerpt of otool output would help to identify the cause of the difference there.

Comment: I would have tried to go into much more details about the `Otool` point in my answer, but having neither an example nor access to the tool, I would have only worked by imagination, concerning alignment, macros, and so on...

Comment: btw ... my comment "... why do you expect the same..." was mainly triggered by my ignorance. After reading ilpelles answer and a bit elsewhere I would also expect to get the same. Sorry for adding my part to the confusion and misunderstanding ;)

Comment: which disassembler is best?  the one that comes with your toolchain, build and disassemble with the same toolchain to get close to but not necessarily the same language.  Closer than using a disassembler from another toolchain.

Comment: @old_timer I am interested in OllyDBG and IDA. However, while I am learning I will stick with gcc and gdb for simplicity. I did not know mac osx had a native debugger.

Comment: fair enough as you are already aware the syntax will change between tool vendors, and you just mentally translate between languages...

Comment: @MrBerry OllyDBG and IDA are Intel-syntax (IIRC), so picking gcc and gdb is a bit unfortunate (unless you plan to use intel-syntax option switch rigorously). In linux around Intel syntax the common tools are: nasm (assembler, has also ndisasm disassembler), edb-debugger (needs to be compiled form sources), gcc and tools around with intel syntax switch... BTW about std::cout large code -> that stream handler can format almost any type value into human readable string, with many options like precision or filler-chars, so indeed that takes hundreds/thousands of instructions in machine code.

Comment: @MrBerry "*I don't know why I suppose they would be the same, perhaps because from the same program I assume they have the same binary code and that translates upwards to assembly?*" If every compiler compiled the same C++ code into the same assembly, there would be no need for compilers from multiple vendors anymore, that would be redundant. In reality, different compilers implement different aspects of the C++ standard, in different ways, with different techniques and optimizations, etc. That means different vendors end up generating different assembly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That makes sense. I did not understand that. I am a beginner, and I need to study how compilers work to fully grasp that concept. As well as many other CS concepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The differences you are experiencing are not in the disassembled program, but rather in the syntax used to represent machine instructions.

Assembly is a very low-level language, in which there is a 1-to-1 mapping between *machine instructions* and *mnemonics*. The former are sequences of bits, possibly of variable length---as in the case of x86 architectures. This representation is directly interpreted by the CPU to carry out the work associated with the *semantic* of the instruction. Assembly language is a "*human readable*" representation of such sequences.

Basically, you can find *any way* to represent the same machine instruction. This is the *assembly syntax*.

Notoriously, for x86 architectures there exist two different syntaxes: **AT&T** and **Intel**. The output which you obtained from GBD is generated according to the AT&T syntax, while the output you got from Godbolt.org is *Intel*'s.

Intel and AT&T syntax are very different from each other in appearance, and possibly this is why you have been thinking that the outcome is not the same. Actually, it's just a different way to represent the *very same* instructions.

These two "*dialects*" for the same architecture's assembly were born with different goals in mind. AT&T syntax was developed at AT&T labs to support the generation of programs for many different CPUs (see the book: [Jeff Duntermann, Assembly Language Step-by-Step](http://books.google.com/books?id=8iR-pBg2aAwC&pg=PA444&lpg=PA444&dq=at%26T%20assembly%20notation&source=bl&ots=qRuZmMJZZ_&sig=kpVVDALWE17TNQZWMTGTwL6j4C4&hl=en&ei=jIXvStHkOIi0sgOu7eiABg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CBQQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=at%26T%20assembly%20notation&f=false)). At the time, AT&T was playing a major role in the history of computers. AT&T (Bell Labs) has been the source of Unix---its paradigm is currently (although partially) committed to by Linux---the C programming language, and many other fundamental tools that we continue to use today.

On the other hand, Intel syntax has been developed, well... by Intel for their own CPUs. Many adopters of the Intel syntax say that it is much neater when prorgamming on Intel CPUs. This might well be the case, as the syntax has been carefully crafted exactly for what the CPU supports.

While the AT&T syntax is no longer used at present days (at least, to the best of my knowledge) to write programs for CPUs other than x86, some of the "culprits" of the syntax are generated from it being more "general".

Then, which one to learn? My choice would be driven by the environment you work on. The whole Unix ecosystem (comprising Linux and Mac Os) has a toolchain (such as `gas`) which directly use that syntax. In the Linux kernel (and other low-level pieces of software) you will definitely find inlined assembly code in AT&T syntax to interact with the hardware. Windows systems, on the other hand, have toolchains (such as `nasm`) which speak the Intel syntax. While compile-time flags can ask these tools to switch to the other syntax (such as the `-M` flag for `objdump`), the habit is to adopt the "native" syntax.

With respect to the specific examples given in the question, they are "incompatible", in the sense that they refer to different portions of the disassembled code, so there is a higher degree of difference across the two.
Indeed, with respect to this GDB output:

```
sub    $0x30, %rsp
mov    0x10c1(%rip), %rdi
lea    0xfb6(%rip), %rsi
```

the corresponding Intel disassembly would be:

```
sub    rsp, 0x30
mov    rdi, QWORD PTR [rip+0x10c1]
lea    rsi, [rip+0xfb6]
```

On the other hand, with respect to the Godbolt.org output:

```
sub rsp, 16
mov DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
mov DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 2
```

the corresponding AT&T disassembly would be:

```
sub    $0x10,%rsp
movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
movl   $0x2,-0x8(%rbp)
```

As you can see, the greatest difference, which might cause a lot of headaches, is related to the fact that the AT&T syntax places the source first and then the destination, while Intel syntax works the other way round.

Comment: This explanation elucidates the matter for me. Different syntax is used to represent the same instructions on different systems. I do not know why I assumed asm was standardized, like binary. I am going to look up the book; that is the type of information I am looking for at the moment.

Comment: Assembly language is defined by the assembler, the tool that you use (or disassembler in this case) for x86 it is not just limited to ATT vs Intel, result on the left or right, but things like DWORD PTR, and the rest of the language, do labels have a colon or not do they have to be preceded by a specific character/symbol.  There are many intel dialect assemblers and disassemblers with incompatible to each other assembly languages, likewise for ATT style.

Comment: To downvoters: my explanation is general, and not specifically bound to the two examples which the OP gave. These, since are randomly cut&pasted code snippets which do not refer to the original higher-level code, should not be taken too much into consideration when replying to the question, IMO. I have anyhow updated my answer showing the corresponding "translations" of both code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

The assembly sequences are not equivalents with different syntax, they are just different, probably due to using different compilers.

First pair:

```
sub $0x30,%rsp             ;rsp -= 0x30
sub rsp,16                 ;rsp -= 0x10
```

Next pair:

```
mov 0x10c1(%rip),%rdi      ;rdi = [rip+0x10c1]  (loads a value)
mov DWORD PTR [rbp-4],1    ;[rbp+4] = 1  (stores an immediate value)
```

Next pair:

```
lea    0xfb6(%rip),%rsi    ;rsi = rip+0xfb6   (loads an offset)
mov DWORD PTR [rbp-8],2    ;[rbp+8] = 2 (stores an immediate value)
```

Both sequences are incomplete, but I don't think it matter much, as the shown sequences already show the differences.

Comment: Apparently the OP just cut&pasted random portions of the disassembly he got! I believe he was not interested in the actual disassembled instructions, rather on why the syntax looked so different.

Comment: @ilpelle - ok, but still there is the difference of `rsp -= 48` versus `rsp -= 16`, at function entry, which would indicate a different compiler and/or build environment.

Comment: or they could be different functions with a different number of local variables. We're not sure the OP picked the actual disassembly of `main`. In particular, the GDB disasm is using RIP-relative to load global variables, which are not present in the example provided. These could be library internal variables. The address `0x100002010` doesn't sound to me as if it's the address of the constant string used in the program. I'm just guessing from a 3-lines example :-)

Answer (score -5):

Because there is not a 1 to 1 relationship between source code and assembly.  The compiler would likely generate the same assembly for the following statements:

```
x = x + 1
```

and

```
x++;
```

both of which would be compiled to something like

```
add dword ptr [rdi], 1
```

So, when we dissassemble that, which one should it be disassembled to?  `x = x+1` or `x++`? This applies to virtually every statement of your program - if there is more than one way of expressing what happens in the source language, and the effects are the same, the compiler may choose to translate both of them to the same output.  After which, you have no way of knowing which one was used.

Comment: didnt downvote, but I also cannot follow you. Shouldnt `x = x+1;` and `x++;` result in the same assembly?

Comment: A disassembler is applied to compiled code, not source code.

Comment: "After which, you have no way of knowing which one was used." ...erm... you should definitely take a look at this awesome tool: https://godbolt.org/ (it doesnt do anything that you cannot do with your own compiler, but it is doing it in an awesome way :P)

Comment: @tobi303 I believe you misunderstood what dave was saying. Basically, if you have `x = x + 1` and you have `x++`, they could both compile down to something like `add dword ptr [rdi], 1`. If you only have the assembly, you have no way of knowing whether it was originally `x = x + 1` or `x++`

Comment: Not my DV either - a disassembler produces something like assembly source code, not C++ source code. Suppose you have a wood sculpture and ask someone to describe the log from which it was carved. There are many answers.

Comment: @tobi303 that is the point.  they result in the same assembly.  So why would you expect two different dissassemblers to produce the same source code from the assembly?

Comment: @NeilButterworth you are completely misunderstanding my point.  "A disassembler is applied to compiled code" - ok, so, if two programs compile down to the SAME compiled code, like in my examples, and we are not trying to take that assembly, and run it through a disassembler, which one should it disassemble to - `x = x+1` or `x++`?  Since it can't know, you shouldn't expect two different disassemblers to always have the same output.

Comment: @dave As far as I can tell, the OP is applying different disassemblers to the same executable and getting unexpectedly different results.

Comment: @NeilButterworth correct.  and my answer explains why them being different should not be unexpected.

Comment: @dave No it doesn't - I don't think you understand what a disassembler does. It produces assembly language mnemonics, not C++ code. What you are talking about would be a decompiler.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Does it take machine code and try to figure out what the assembly code was?  Is there more than one way of expressing the same machine code in assembly code?

Comment: @dave There is a one-to-one mapping (in both directions) between machine code and assembly language.

Comment: @NeilButterworth no there's not.  literally the first sentence in wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language says "there is a very strong (but often not one-to-one) correspondence between the language and the architecture's machine code instructions"

Comment: @dave  A statement it never then explains - I've written several assemblers and disassemblers, and they all used a one-to-one mapping, as did all the other assemblers and disassemblers I've ever used.

Comment: @NeilButterworth :Not all. MASM/TASM often would emit a different set of instructions than what was specified in the assembly code (usually for processor compatibility). For instance if the target was 8086 and you did `rol ax, 4` it would emit 4 `rol ax, 1` instructions . When disassembled it would appear as 4 `rol ax, 1`. One to one mapping isn't always the case. The most interesting code that MASM/TASM would generate for 8086 targets was when pushing an immediate value.